# What does "feed the notion" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does ***feed the notion*** mean in this context?
(Source:[Link](http://www.marketwatch.com/story/investors-are-breathing-a-sigh-of-relief-over-france-for-now-2017-05-07))

> "A French presidential election victory Sunday by centrist Emmanuel Macron, a former investment banker who campaigned as an unabashedly pro-European reformer, over euroskeptic nationalist Marine Le Pen will **feed the notion** that a populist wave that led to Britain’s Brexit vote last June and Donald Trump’s U.S. presidential victory has crested."

Comment: This means the Macron's wining will support this claim that the populism wave is gone!

Comment: This isn't the first time you're shying away from doing basic research on your own (and including it in your question), hence my flagging and voting it down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we **feed** something (or someone) it grows stronger.

We can feed a baby.

We can feed a plant.

The verb **feed** thus acquires figurative meaning "to sustain by providing anything that causes *something* to become stronger".

We can feed a fire.

We can feed a furnace.

The something need not be a physical thing, but can be anything that can be conceived of as capable of becoming stronger or more intense if given what it needs.

We can feed fears.

We can feed suspicion.

We can feed a notion.

Answer (score 2):

For example, you could use as a synonym the expression **fuel the idea**.